# Avoid a Trigger firing when data updated by trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Im trying to keep two columns from differant tables in sync, i had thought to use two triggers, both work independently but if i have them both compiled then i get an error due to 'mutated data', i think i understand that its causing a bit of a loop to happen but not sure how to avoid it.

Trigger 1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SCPOMGR.TRG_UDTDFUVIEW_RVIEWD_MNTH
AFTER UPDATE
OF REVIEWED_THIS_MONTH ON SCPOMGR.UDT_DFUVIEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (:NEW.REVIEWED_THIS_MONTH = 1 )
THEN 
update scpomgr.dfuexception
set dfuexception.u_review  = 1 
where dfuexception.dmdunit=:old.dmdunit and dfuexception.loc=:old.loc
and dfuexception.exception = 20000 and dfuexception.u_review = 0;
ELSE 
update scpomgr.dfuexception
set dfuexception.u_review  = 0 
where dfuexception.dmdunit=:old.dmdunit and dfuexception.loc=:old.loc
and dfuexception.exception = 20000 and dfuexception.u_review = 1
;
 END IF;
END;
/
```

Trigger 2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SCPOMGR.TRG_DFUEXCEPTION_RVIEWD
AFTER UPDATE
OF u_review ON SCPOMGR.DFUEXCEPTION
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF ( :NEW.u_review = 1 and :new.exception = 20000 )
THEN 
update scpomgr.udt_dfuview
set udt_dfuview.REVIEWED_THIS_MONTH  = 1 
where udt_dfuview.dmdunit=:old.dmdunit and udt_dfuview.loc=:old.loc
and udt_dfuview.REVIEWED_THIS_MONTH = 0
;
ELSE 
update scpomgr.udt_dfuview
set udt_dfuview.REVIEWED_THIS_MONTH  = 0 
where udt_dfuview.dmdunit=:old.dmdunit and udt_dfuview.loc=:old.loc
and udt_dfuview.REVIEWED_THIS_MONTH = 1
;
 END IF;

END;
/
```

So im looking for a way to keep the u_review field and reviewed_this_month columns in sync when matched by dmdunit and loc which are PKs on both tables.
This needs to be closer to real time opposed to an overnight sync

I have looked at a couple of other questions and answers but the solutions didnt seem to apply to 2 tables and keeping data aligned.

Any help is appreciated

EDIT:
Full error is:

```
ORA-04091: table SCPOMGR.UDT_DFUVIEW is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SCPOMGR.TRG_DFUEXCEPTION_RVIEWD", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCPOMGR.TRG_DFUEXCEPTION_RVIEWD'
ORA-06512: at "SCPOMGR.TRG_UDTDFUVIEW_RVIEWD_MNTH", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCPOMGR.TRG_UDTDFUVIEW_RVIEWD_MNTH'
```

Reason we have two columns of data is because the dfuexception table contains system exceptions against a small list of articles. Then the udt_dfuview contains almost all articles. If we review an article for any reason then its deemed OK, and so we tick the udt_dfuview. reviewed_this_month, if it also exists as a dfuexception we dont want users to be reviewing it twice, so we tick the u_review box for exception 20000. The same applies in reverse, if they get to the dfuexception first then we want to tick the reviewed_this_month on the udt_dfuview to prevent that user or another user looking into something that has already been reviewed.

Comment: You're storing same data in two places. Is this a good design in the first place?

Comment: Can you post the full error message (with sensitive information removed if necessary)? This will help others if they run in to the same thing.

Comment: Also, agreed with Salman. There might be a good reason or you inherited the design and the ship has sailed. But this is the exact reason it's advisable to not have redundant data.

Comment: I agree with others that this smells of a poor design, but if we assume you're not able to change it, you need a way to track where the update originates, and check against that. You might need a new "update source" column on both tables which the trigger can check against and then update or not based on that. Still not a very good design, but it would in theory stop a repeated cycle of updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution, I can think of, is to add one `NUMBER(1)` data type column(`UPDATE_DATA_SOURCE`) in both the tables `UDT_DFUVIEW` and `DFUEXCEPTION` with default value as 0.

Then while you are updating table data from trigger set `UPDATE_DATA_SOURCE` to 1.

and in both the triggers, set the `WHEN` condition to `WHEN UPDATE_DATA_SOURCE = 0`

SQLs for adding the column:

```
ALTER TABLE UDT_DFUVIEW ADD UPDATE_DATA_SOURCE NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0;
ALTER TABLE DFUEXCEPTION ADD UPDATE_DATA_SOURCE NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0;
```

**TRIGGER1:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SCPOMGR.TRG_UDTDFUVIEW_RVIEWD_MNTH
AFTER UPDATE
OF REVIEWED_THIS_MONTH ON SCPOMGR.UDT_DFUVIEW
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.UPDATE_DATA_SOURCE = 0) -- Added this WHEN condition
BEGIN
IF (:NEW.REVIEWED_THIS_MONTH = 1 )
THEN 
update scpomgr.dfuexception
set dfuexception.u_review  = 1, UPDATE_DATA_SOURCE = 1 -- Added this 
where dfuexception.dmdunit=:old.dmdunit and dfuexception.loc=:old.loc
and dfuexception.exception = 20000 and dfuexception.u_review = 0;
ELSE 
update scpomgr.dfuexception
set dfuexception.u_review  = 0, UPDATE_DATA_SOURCE = 1 -- Added this 
where dfuexception.dmdunit=:old.dmdunit and dfuexception.loc=:old.loc
and dfuexception.exception = 20000 and dfuexception.u_review = 1
;
 END IF;
END;
/
```

**TRIGGER2:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SCPOMGR.TRG_DFUEXCEPTION_RVIEWD
AFTER UPDATE
OF u_review ON SCPOMGR.DFUEXCEPTION
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.UPDATE_DATA_SOURCE = 0) -- Added this WHEN condition
BEGIN
IF ( :NEW.u_review = 1 and :new.exception = 20000 )
THEN 
update scpomgr.udt_dfuview
set udt_dfuview.REVIEWED_THIS_MONTH  = 1, UPDATE_DATA_SOURCE = 1 -- Added this  
where udt_dfuview.dmdunit=:old.dmdunit and udt_dfuview.loc=:old.loc
and udt_dfuview.REVIEWED_THIS_MONTH = 0
;
ELSE 
update scpomgr.udt_dfuview
set udt_dfuview.REVIEWED_THIS_MONTH  = 0, UPDATE_DATA_SOURCE = 1 -- Added this 
where udt_dfuview.dmdunit=:old.dmdunit and udt_dfuview.loc=:old.loc
and udt_dfuview.REVIEWED_THIS_MONTH = 1
;
 END IF;

END;
/
```

**Note**: Keep in mind that this solution will work only in case you are not expecting the same record to be **updated multiple times** as `UPDATE_DATA_SOURCE` will be already 1 in the second update and your trigger will not be executed.

Comment: Thanks for this - I could add a reset of the update_data_source column in our overnight batch process and a catch all alignment using a simple update script, so that users can make changes to the DFUs once per day that will be replicated immediately, otherwise they will be replicated that night.
This might be the best solution if its our only option, thankyou

Comment: Have ended up using an alternative solution by changing the relationships between two tables to allow me to update a single field. Although the solution provided would have resolved the problem. Thanks.